# Triangle inequality

Tags: function, python-3.x, return-value

I have to write a program that takes user input for the sides of a triangle and prints if it is a right triangle and what the area is. My assignment also asks us to make sure that no side is longer than the sum of the other two sides. I have tried to figure out how to get my code to work for a side not being longer than the sums of the other two sides and prompt the user to start over, but I am at a loss. I am also having an issue where when my program runs it prints the words none, I think it has to do with my def right_tri function but I am not sure why it would be doing that.

Here is my code any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
def area(a, b, c):
    s = (a + b + c) / 2

   area = (s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)) **0.5
   return format(area, '.2f')

def right_tri(a, b, c):
    if (b**2 + c**2 == a**2):
       print('Is a right triangle')

else:
      print('Is not a right triangle')

def main () :

    a = int(input('Enter longest side of the triangle'))
    b = int(input('Enter the second side of the triangle'))
    c = int(input('Enter the thrid side of the triangle'))

    print('Area is:', triangle.area(a, b, c))
    print(triangle.right_tri(a, b, c))
    print(is_sum(a, b, c))

 def is_sum(a, b, c):
     if (a > b + c) or (b > a + c) or (c > a + b):
        print ('One side is longer than the sum of the other two sides')
 else:
     return True

main ()
```

Comment: For any triangle **it's impossible that one side is longer than the sum of the other two sides**! There's absolutely no need to test for this condition.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the indentation of your code is correct (as python relies on it) following should be the implementation of `right_tri`,

```
def right_tri(a, b, c):
    if ((b**2 + c**2 == a**2) || (a**2 + c**2 == b**2) || (b**2 + a**2 == c**2)):
       print('Is a right triangle')

    else:
      print('Is not a right triangle')
```

The reason for multiple conditions is because, you never know if the user is giving hypotenuse for `a` or `b`  or `c`.

Answer (score 0):

In right_tri function you need to use a return statement, just like

```
    def right_tri(a, b, c):
        if (b**2 + c**2 == a**2):
            return 'Is a right triangle'
        else:
            return 'Is not a right triangle'
```